# Excel to DataGrid Exponential Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, oledb

I'm using the following code to display an excel file in a data grid, the problem is, large numbers are being displayed as exponential form i.e. 1236548965132160 is displayed as 1.23654896513216E+15 in the grid,

```
string xlsxString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
OleDbConnection excelOleDBConnection = new OleDbConnection(xlsxString);
excelOleDBConnection.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapterForExcelFile = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelOleDBConnection);
DataTable dataTableForTheAdapter = new DataTable();
dataAdapterForExcelFile.Fill(dataTableForTheAdapter);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTableForTheAdapter.DefaultView;
```

I need to remove this exponential form from the code, and not the excel, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

```
DataTable dataTableForTheAdapter = new DataTable();
dataAdapterForExcelFile.FillSchema(dataTableForTheAdapter, SchemaType.Source);
for(int i = 0; i < dataTableForTheAdapter.Columns.Count; i++)
   if (dataTableForTheAdapter.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(double))
      dataTableForTheAdapter.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(decimal);
dataAdapterForExcelFile.Fill(dataTableForTheAdapter);
```

or:

```
     this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTableForTheAdapter.DefaultView;
     for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType == typeof(double))
           this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N";
     }
```